# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Model>'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

When using `Select()` I am getting this error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<OgrenciEvi.Areas.Message.Models.MessageModel>'.

```
SiteContext db = new SiteContext();
[Route]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new ViewModel();
    int UserID = int.Parse(User.Identity.GetID());
    model.Messages = db.Message.Where(m => m.ReceiverID == UserID || m.SenderID == UserID).Select(m=>m.SenderUser.Name).ToList();

    return View(model);
}
```

How I fix it ?

Edit:

```
public class MessageModel
{
    [Key]
    public int MessageID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Boş mesaj gönderilemez.")]
    public string MessageContent { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int SenderID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int ReceiverID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime SendingDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool IsSeen { get; set; }

    public virtual UserModel SenderUser { get; set; }
    public virtual UserModel ReceiverUser { get; set; }


    MessageModel() {
        SendingDate = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

userModel:

```
public class UserModel
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [Required (ErrorMessage ="İsim alanı boş geçilemez.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Soyadı alanı boş geçilemez.")]
    public string Surname { get; set; }


    [RegularExpression(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}" +
                       @"\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\" +
                       @".)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$",
                       ErrorMessage = "E-Posta adresi geçersiz.")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Mail { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [NotMapped] // Does not effect with your database
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    public int Gender { get; set; }
    [RegularExpression("^[0-9]*$", ErrorMessage ="Telefon numarası geçersiz.")]
    public string PhoneNumber{ get; set; }
    public int SmokeStatus { get; set; }
    public DateTime RegistrationDate { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public string ReturnUrl{ get; set; }
    [Range(1900,2000, ErrorMessage ="Doğum yılı 1900 ile 2000 yılları arasında olmalı.")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Yaş alanı boş geçilemez.")]
    public int BirthYear { get; set; }

    public string FacebookID { get; set; }
    public bool Manager { get; set; }

    public int AccessFacebook { get; set; }
    public int AccessInstagram { get; set; }
    public int AccessPhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public int AccessTwitter { get; set; }

    public List<LookingForaMateModel> LFMate { get; set; }
    public List<LookingForaHome> LFHome { get; set; }
    public List<AlbumModel> Album { get; set; }
    public List<PropertyTransferModel> PropertyTransfer{ get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SenderID")]
    public List<MessageModel> SenderUser { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ReceiverID")]
    public List<MessageModel> ReceiverUser { get; set; }



    public UserModel() {
        RegistrationDate = DateTime.Now;
    }


}
```

I want "direct message" for my web site and the design look like facebook messenger so there is a panel on left side. I should get list Message's sender name and last message. But I couldn't make it :)

Comment: What is type of model.Messages?

Comment: Please mention the type of left operand.

Comment: Can you tell us what is the data type model.Messages? Why do you use select ?

Comment: There is not enough context here for anyone to be able to answer your question. The cause of the error message is clear enough, because the compiler message is itself clear, but why you have a field called `Name` that has type `int`, and why you think you can create a list from a sequence of values from that field, and then assign it to a variable expecting an enumeration of a completely different type, is not _at all_ clear.

Comment: Please share the model class of Message .After going through your code and exception message mentioned ,i believe you have define [User.Name] as Int there . !!

Comment: How can you convert list of `int` to list of `MessageModel`? There should be an implicit conversion otherwise this type conversion error will be thrown. If you try `.Select(m=>m).ToList()` assuming the type of `m` is `MessageModel` it should work. Or all that you want is a list of integers then change the left hand side variable to `List<int>`.

Comment: You don't need to use select here... You will get list of messages based on the where clause and then you can do whatever you want to do with it. If you don't use select you will not get the error. So that solves your current problem. Now how this does not work as per expectation is a different matter. If removing select solve your error problem then please let us know. For other issue please raise different question with details about what is expected and what unexpected you are seeing or receiving.

Comment: Hmmm is `m.SenderUser.Name` type `int`? Otherwise, the exception should not be complaining about a `List<int>` but `List<string>`...anyhow, if you want an answer, you need to show the code for your `ViewModel` class.

Answer (score 0):

You still havn't shown your code for the ViewModel class. But Assuming that model.Messages is of type `List<Message>`, the following should work:

```
    var model = new ViewModel();
    int UserID = int.Parse(User.Identity.GetID());
    model.Messages = db.Message.Where(m => m.ReceiverID == UserID || m.SenderID == UserID).ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

Make Messages type IEnumerable

Comment: Generic < string>

Comment: What makes you think that changing the type of the `Messages` property is even an option? Sure, if it has type `IEnumerable`, it can accept a reference to any `IEnumerable`, including a list of a completely different type of objects than expected. But that doesn't mean that doing so would make _any_ sense at all in the rest of the code. The goal here is to solve the OP's problem, not just to somehow stop the compiler error.